# Can we put section headers to Recycler View in xamarin android?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I am working on recycler view in xamarin. I tried the example from http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/RecyclerViewer/ and it works fine. But I would like to know that can we put section headers to recyclerview. If so any suggestion on how to keep headers will be helpful.

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: I have done this using android SDK. If you simply want the code i can give it to you.

Comment: can you please provide the link